# msmtp 1.8.22 override from address when sending via php

Tags: php, amazon-ses, msmtp

I have the following config file for msmtp

```
account         default
host         SES_HOST
port         587
timeout         5
auth         on
tls          on
tls_starttls    on
tls_trust_file     /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
syslog          on
set_from_header on
allow_from_override off
user         SES_USERNAME
password     SES_PASSWORD
from         SES_VERIFIED_EMAIL
```

php.ini

`sendmail_path = /usr/local/bin/msmtp -ti`

I want to make sure all emails sent via php use the SES_VERIFIED_EMAIL in the from header so SES does NOT reject the email. I thought setting the `from` `allow_from_override on` and `allow_from_override off` would mean that email send from php with a from header that is NOT SES_VERIFIED_EMAIL would be replaced by SES_VERIFIED_EMAIL so the message will be sent

But I can only send emails via php where the from header is already put in as `SES_VERIFIED_EMAIL` but I need it to work in all cases. It doesn't appear the from header is being replaced

I want msmtp to override the From header to `SES_VERIFIED_EMAIL` so it does get sent. I thought the settings above would do it.

```
<?php
    $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: NOTSESVERIFYED@example.com'       . "\r\n" .
                 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
set_from_header on
```

To:

```
set_from_header off
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from               SES_VERIFIED_EMAIL
rewrite_domain     SES_VERIFIED_EMAIL
```

The rewrite_domain option is used to rewrite the domain part of the From header. This is useful if you want to send mail from a domain that is not your own. The domain part of the From header is rewritten to the value of the rewrite_domain option. The local part of the From header is not changed.

Comment: I need local part to also be rewritten otherwise SES won’t send. I don’t understand why what I have isn’t working. Is ‘from’ NOT the from header?